Cryptographic strength of AES-GCM-256 for classical and Quantum
How can the strength be calculated, of both the GMAC and the encryption for AES-GCM-256, with AES key of 256 bit, for classical and quantum computers?

Security levels in NIST Post-quantum project: e.g. AES-128 vs SHA-256 and Is AES-256 a post-quantum secure cipher or not? make the dupe.

I'd like to add this link which is more specific to the authentication tag (and quantum crypt-analysis).

There have also been a number of papers on the practical cost of Grover's algorithm against AES, like this one at the NIST Fifth PQC Standardization Conference.

Evgeni, do these links provide enough of an answer for your question? If not could you indicate which parts you've doubt about and [edit] those in your question? If you've any other concern feel free to comment below.
